# npm cron blocking Express.JS HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, express, cron

I'm trying the [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module from npm in my [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) application.

The app structure is pretty simple, I have a function to connect to the database, and in there I register all the various modules which handle HTTP requests, something like this:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
export default ({ config }) => {
    let api = Router();

    connectAllDbs(config, ({mysql}) => {

        userModule({api, config, mysql});
        // other modules...
    });

    return api;
};
```

Now I've written a cron and added it after those HTTP modules are loaded, as it also depends on a database connection

```
const cron = new CronJob('* */30 * * *', () => {
    // do stuff w/ mysql
});
cron.start();
```

With this addition some of the HTTP requests to the node server are randomly *'pending'* in the browser

[image: pending http request]

I've started reading up on [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) and [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/worker_threads.html), but these seem arduous as the external file is now outside of my nice babel-enabled codebase, so I have to figure out some voodoo in package.json to get a script outside of index.js to flow through all of that...

Is this expected behavior with the cron module? I didn't see anything on the [README](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#readme) or known issues; I'm surprised nobody else has encountered this, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong - any idea what that might be?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with one solution which uses [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

To cope with the need to go through npm to leverage the babel setup without having to create another entry point (adding `scripts` entries in package.json), I created a conditional block in the existing entry point (index.js) script, something like this

```
//--------------------------------------------------
// Run the CRON
//--------------------------------------------------
if(process.argv.includes('cron')) {
    runCron();
}
//--------------------------------------------------
// Handle HTTP requests
//--------------------------------------------------
else {
    // Start express -------------------------------
    let app = express();
    app.server = http.createServer(app);

    // Fork the cron process -----------------------
    const spawned = spawn('npm', ['run', 'cron']);
}
```

I'd prefer to have a second entry-point, but not immediately sure how to do that, so this was the easiest solution for me.